# data.table minus one vector

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table, say like so:

```
dt = data.table(param_1 = c(1,3,5), param_2 = c(2,4,6))
dt
       param_1 param_2
1:       1       2
2:       3       4
3:       5       6
```

and a constant vector, say this one:

```
s = c(1, 0.5)
```

and I want to compute 'vector minus table', i.e. `s - dt` and expect

```
 0 | -1.5
-2 | -3.5
-4 | -5.5
```

but I get

```
> s - dt
   param_1 param_2
1:     0.0    -1.5
2:    -2.5    -3.0
3:    -4.0    -5.5
>
```

So it seems as if the order of the columns is somehow randmly switched (the first row is ok but the second row is weird!). This also happens if `s` is a named vector with names equal to the names of the data table (in correct order).

How can I get the table as expected?

Comment: How do you get -3.0 in row 2?

Comment: @Sotos: You mean in the result R gives me? I think it goes along the lines provided in the answer below

Comment: So it's `-3.5` then, i.e. you made a typo

Comment: @Sotos: No, it's not a typo (Ill revert the edit). Please read the answer carefully! The convention on how this unclear operation (vector minus data table) is interpreted here really mixes things up, the 3 is 'correct' in the sense that R really gives this result ...

Comment: Oh, right. My bad. Apologies. I thought that was your expected outcome (people tend to put it at the end hence as soon as my eye went to it I immediately thought "expected output")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can either use `Map`

```
dt[, Map(`-`, s, .SD)]
```

Or replicate 's' to make the lengths same and subtract from 'dt'

```
s[col(dt)] - dt
```

Note that when we subtract a `vector` from a data.frame or data.table, the subtraction happens in the column order i.e. all the elements of the first column are subtracted, then goes to second column and so on.  What happens is that with a simple subtraction

```
s - dt
```

the first element of 's' gets subtracted from 1st column, 1st row of 'dt', then the second element of 's' subtract from the 2nd element of 1st column.  Because of recycling, this gets repeated with the vector and the output is different

Comment: Makes sense and your solution seems to work. Thanks :-)